# Rails WebSocket Client never fires OnOpen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I'm using [Faye WebSockets](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby)  for my rails application and am trying to connect to a pre-existing websocket server at http://www.websocket.org/echo.html.

However, my websocket's OnOpen event is never triggered, and there's no errors or status at all to the thing.  Here's what the rails code looks like:

```
def make_websocket
    if @@ws
        return
    end
    p "Making the websocket"
    ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('ws://echo.websocket.org/') 

    ws.on :open do |event|
        p "connection has been opened"
        @@ws = ws
        self.clear_queue
    end

    ws.on :message do |event|
        p [:message, event.data]
    end

    ws.on :error do |event|
        p "WebSockets error"
        p [:error, event.data]
    end

    ws.on :close do |event|
        p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
        @@ws = nil
    end
end
```

However, the only thing to be found in the log file is "Making the websocket".  Is there something obvious I'm missing, or does anyone have a different gem that I could use as a client in a rails server?
TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code needs to be wrapped in an `EM.run` block